# ListView SelectedItem Alternating Background Color

Tags: wpf, listview, background-color

I am using (new to 3.5) AlternationIndex trigger on a ListView to apply an alternating background color like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#300761AE" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This part works great and the ListView looks exactly how I want. The only issue I have is with the SelectedItem's background color. For my list, items can't actually be selected since contextually that makes no sense. What I am trying to find is a way to have the SelectedItem's background color be nothing so the parent ListViewItem's color shines through. Transparent doesn't work because that essentially equates to white and the alternating style disappears when I use transparent. It also wouldn't let me set it to null.

I know I need to change the SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, but I couldn't figure out how to setup the binding to find the parent ListViewItem's background color. Here was the attempt:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=Background}" />
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried attaching a event handler to the SelectionChanged event and set SelectedItem to null

```
    private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listview = sender as ListView;

        if (listview != null)
            listview.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Comment: You could also try using an ItemsControl instead of ListView as you can't select items in a ItemsControl, I think.

Comment: As usual, that's what I get for working so late. Your idea worked perfectly. I'd be afraid to try and change the view to an ItemsControl because of how heavily customized it is right now so luckily this took care of it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

just try with this

```
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

http://imduff.wordpress.com/2008/03/01/change-highlight-color-when-an-item-in-a-listview-is-selected/

Comment: That is the premise I based my attempts on, but since the background color alternates I can't just set an arbitrary color. I need it to honor whatever the color of the row pre-selection was since it changes depending on row index.